# The MySQL Connection could not be established., before it was joomla but i have change it into worpress

Tags: database, mysql, sql

When i have removed all the file from the `public_html` and installed WordPress ... I got this error:

> The following errors were found :
>
> The MySQL Connection could not be established.

do i need to delete MySQL on the database when i delete the Joomla! file...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you have assigned the user/pass to the database via your cPanel. And that those credentials match what WordPress expects. Usually, the WP install process will do this for you. (I assume that you created a new WP installation, and are not trying to re-use an existing database.)

Also, you should obfuscate the URL in your screenshot...you don't want to give out that confidential info to hackers who might be lurking, even though that possibility is remote.

Your screenshot also shows (I think) your database credentials. Again, not good. For future questions, just copy the actual error message, watching out for PII (Personally Identifiable Information; in this case: credentials, URLs, and other stuff).